# How to check if a Task is running and restart if it is not running

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library, multitasking

I have a few tasks that I want to run for very long periods of time. I want to start the tasks and then check in a loop if they are still running, and to restart the task  if one of them is cancelled or otherwise stopped.
The code I have does not detect that the tasks are started, and restarts them over and over again.
Can somebody help me please? Or is there a better way of doing what I want?
Thank you.

```
    public async Task TaskBx(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        while (true)
        { 
         //Do stuff
         await Task.Delay(500);

        }
    }
    public async Task TaskAx(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        while (true)
        {
         //Do stuff
         await Task.Delay(500);

        }
    }





    private async Task StartTrade(CancellationToken ct)
    {

        Task TA = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TaskAx(ct));
        Task TB = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TaskBx(ct));

        while (true)
        {

            if ((TA != null) && (TA.IsCompleted == true)) { _ = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TaskAx(ct)); Console.WriteLine("Start TaskA"); } else { Console.WriteLine("Started A"); }
            if ((TB != null) && (TB.IsCompleted == true)) { _ = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TaskBx(ct)); Console.WriteLine("Start TaskB"); } else { Console.WriteLine("Started B"); }

            await Task.Delay(50);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Still not clear what do you want. Maybe better to explain what do you want achieve rather than how do you want?

Comment: Inside your `while()` loop you are not changing the variable `TA`/`TB`, so when `TA.IsCompleted` is returning `true` it stays that way, resulting in new task created in every iteration.

Comment: Is it an option to include exception handling inside the loop in the `TaskAx` and `TaskBx` methods, so that you don't have to restart them in case of an error?

Answer (score 2):

You're not re-assigning `TA` and `TB` to your new `Task` instance.  Additionally you're not disposing the old instance, which is a bad idea. Finally, there is no need to call `Task.Factory.StartNew()`.

Something like this might work better, I did change your delays and add more output to better see what's happening...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var token = new CancellationToken();

        var mainTask = StartTrade(token);

        while (true)
        {
            if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public async static Task TaskBx(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter TaskBx");

        while (true)
        {
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                break;

            //Do stuff

            await Task.Delay(1000);

            break; // For demonstration.
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Exit TaskBx");
    }

    public async static Task TaskAx(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter TaskAx");

        while (true)
        {
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                break;

            //Do stuff

            await Task.Delay(2000);

            break; // For demonstration.
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Exit TaskAx");
    }

    private async static Task StartTrade(CancellationToken ct)
    {

        Task TA = TaskAx(ct);
        Task TB = TaskBx(ct);

        while (true)
        {
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                break;

            if ((TA != null) && (TA.IsCompleted == true))
            {
                TA.Dispose();
                TA = null;

                TA = TaskAx(ct);
                Console.WriteLine("Start TaskA");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Started A");
            }

            if ((TB != null) && (TB.IsCompleted == true))
            {
                TB.Dispose();
                TB = null;

                TB = TaskBx(ct);
                Console.WriteLine("Start TaskB");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Started B");
            }

            await Task.Delay(500);

        }

    }
```

Comment: @DianaM00nshine Great! My explanation isn't very good though... If we don't wrap a `Task` inside another `Task` (via `Task.Factory.StartNew()`) then we quickly find out that we can't restart it so we have to recreate it. Combine that with disposing the old instance and the solution becomes more obvious.

Comment: @DianaM00nshine Keep in mind that if `TA/TB` are ever set to `null` somewhere else in the future then your code will incorrectly print "Started …". This should probably be changed.

Comment: Regarding if it's a bad idea to leave the tasks undisposed, please look at this: [Do I need to dispose of Tasks?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks/) **TL;DR:** *No. Don't bother disposing of your tasks.*

Comment: @TheodorZoulias *...not unless performance or scalability testing reveals that you need to dispose of them...* Which may or may not apply in this situation. Anyway, It's **never** a bad idea to dispose of anything and everything that you instantiate.

Comment: I'll also point out that the edit changed the *spirit* of that (poorly written) sentence, but did improve it.

Comment: In principal I would like to agree with you, but in practice if you try to dispose **every** task you create you'll probably end up with a maintenance nightmare ridden with bugs. It is very easy to introduce a race condition where you dispose a task and concurrently access one of its properties from another thread without synchronization. And if you dispose them sometimes only, then what's the point? Consistency: either dispose them always or never. And since the leader architect of the TPL advises to not bother disposing tasks, it's a pretty easy decision for me.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I'm not sure you're paying attention here... nobody is saying that `using (var task = Task.Delay(1000)) { await task; }` is a good idea. In this situation, it makes perfect sense to dispose `TA/TB` before dropping the reference and creating a new one. Any attempt to access one of the properties **should** result in an exception. You're what's known as ***wrong***.

Comment: Please clarify. Do you say that disposing a task makes sense in this specific case for some particular reason, but doesn't make sense in general?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Okay, let me try this again... anytime you hold a reference to an `IDisposable` instance, then call `Dispose()` on it when you're done with it. It's as simple as that. (Yes I know `Main` above doesn't dispose of `mainTask`, but it should.)

Comment: So there is no misunderstanding on my part. You actually do advocate that all tasks should be **always** disposed. Two questions: 1) Do you follow this advice yourself? 2) How do you explain that Stephen Toub [disagrees with your opinion and advises the exact opposite](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks/)?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Like I said, I don't think you're paying attention. This is correct, and good practice, in this situation. You may do whatever you like of course. That is all.

Comment: You clarified just previously that you are not talking specifically for this situation, but for every situation. By the way I do pay enough attention to notice that you didn't answer any of my two previous questions. Please answer at least the next one: *❝Any attempt to access one of the properties should result in an exception.❞* Try this: `var task = Task.FromResult(0); task.Dispose(); Console.WriteLine(task.Result);` No exception, the value `0` is printed in the console. How do you reconcile the discrepancy between how the tasks **should** behave, and how they **actually** behave?

Comment: @rfmodulator It seems that I can't get it to work right. After I cancel and restart the task "Task.IsCompleted" gives "true"  on each iteration , and the task restarts on each iteration.

Comment: @DianaM00nshine That's probably because your `ct.IsCancellationRequested` is still `true`, which short circuits everything in my example above. In order to *cancel then restart*, as opposed to *complete then restart*, you would need to get a new `CancellationToken`, because they can't be reset.

Comment: @rfmodulator I just figured that out , but thanks anyway.